# SAS: Unzipping multiple .dat files at once

Tags: zip, sas

I want to unzip a file that contains a .dat file using SAS. I have over 100 files to unzip and therefore I want to do it automatically with SAS. I've tried to use the following:

```
FILENAME ZIPFILE SASZIPAM 'Z:\folder\file'; 
DATA newdata; 
INFILE ZIPFILE(file.dat) dsd DLM='|'; 
INPUT var1 var2 var$;
RUN;
```

That doesn't work. Is there a problem when you use ZIPFILE SASCIPAM to unzip a .dat file? I have SAS 9.3.

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use macros to do it, but it might get a bit messy. SAS has for many years offered the `X` command for contacting the command prompt. This method requires that you have downloaded a free file archiver/de-compresser (e.g. 7-Zip, WinRAR etc.).

I like using the command line version of 7-Zip. I use a 32-bit machine, so you might have to use a different .exe file.

The syntax for unzipping multiple files in a directory:

```
data _null_;
    X "cd (7-Zip_installed_location)"; <=== File that contains the 7za.exe
    X "7za e (zip_files_location)*.zip -o(output_destination)";
run;
```

For Example, I have some zip files in the folder called "Compressed":

```
data _null_;
    X "cd C:\7-Zip Comm";
    X "7za e C:\sasdata\Compressed\*.zip -oC:\sasdata\New";
run;
```

`e` stands for "extract".

`*` means for all.

`-o` stands for "output".

Comment: thanks for the helper. I don't have `7za` in my folder but 7zG and typed `data _null_;
    X "cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip"; 
    X "7zG e Z:\Rule605\Exchanges\*.zip -o Z:\Rule605\Exchanges\";
run;` and nothing is going on

Comment: I'm guessing you have a 64-bit machine. I think you need the 7z.dll in the same folder as your 7cg.exe

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen `SASZIPAM` as a file reference type.

I would do this like this:

```
filename zipfile ZIP 'Z:\folder\file.zip';
DATA newdata; 
INFILE ZIPFILE(file.dat) dsd DLM='|'; 
INPUT var1 var2 var$;
RUN;
```

It's possible I am missing that type in the documentation.  Can you paste the ERROR you get in your log?

Comment: If I run your suggested code I get `ERROR: No logical assign for filename ZIPFILE.`. With my previous code, the error that I get is: `ERROR: Invalid data length.
FATAL: Unrecoverable I/O error detected in the execution of the DATA step program.
       Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.`

Comment: my bad, I had LIBname instead of FILEname.  Edited code.  Can you paste a few records from the file.dat file?  Your error sounds like the data step is having problems parsing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes for each of the path will resovle any issue while extracting .z file on windows 7 (SAS 9.3): (FYI - 2nd statement is in one line)

```
data _null_;
x '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "E:\sas\config\Lev1\SASApp\Data\*.Z" -o"E:\sas\config\Lev1\SASApp\Data"'; 
run;
```

Regards
Bhavin